# python: how to sum unique elements respectively of a dataframe column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a df with two columns.

**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':list('aaabbbccc'),'label':[0,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,2]})
print('df\n',df)
```

**Output**

```
df
    label user_id
0      0       a
1      0       a
2      1       a
3      0       b
4      0       b
5      2       b
6      0       c
7      1       c
8      2       c
```

I want to count the element in `label` group by user_id respectively. 
The expected output is shown as follow.

**Expected**

```
  df
    label user_id  label_0  label_1  label_2
0      0       a        2         1         0
1      0       a        2         1         0
2      1       a        2         1         0
3      0       b        2         0         1
4      0       b        2         0         1
5      2       b        2         0         1
6      0       c        1         1         1 
7      1       c        1         1         1
8      2       c        1         1         1
```

Briefly, in column `label_0`, I count the number of `0` in column `label` based on column `user_id`.

Hopefully for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idea is create helper `DataFrame` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `df`:

```
df = (df.join(df.groupby(['user_id', 'label'])
                .size()
                .unstack(fill_value=0)
                .add_prefix('label_'), 'user_id'))
```

---

```
df = (df.join(df.groupby('user_id')['label']
                .value_counts()
                .unstack(fill_value=0)
                .add_prefix('label_'), 'user_id'))
```

Or using [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df = (df.merge(pd.crosstab(df['user_id'], df['label'])
                 .add_prefix('label_'), on='user_id', how='left'))
```

---

```
print (df)
  user_id  label  label_0  label_1  label_2
0       a      0        1        2        0
1       a      1        1        2        0
2       a      1        1        2        0
3       b      1        1        1        1
4       b      2        1        1        1
5       b      0        1        1        1
6       c      0        1        1        1
7       c      1        1        1        1
8       c      2        1        1        1
```

Comment: Thanks! The first two methods work perfectly, but the third method happens an error called 'KeyError: `user_id` '.